# How to save Excel data in other Folder on a Mac?

Tags: excel, directory, save, office365

How can I save an Excel sheet from the MS Office 365 Pro Plus package in folder other than the preinstalled folder?
As soon as I click on the Folder option: "Other"
I can only save it to other folders in OneDrive or Share point, but not into a Mac-folder.
I would be very glad if someone could help me out with this issue!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H13ZT.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnexr.png)

Comment: Did you try File - Save As instead?

Comment: After restarting Excel it magically worked I don't know why this issue occured